# Putting Textfield value into array, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, jtextfield

I have two JTextFields called field1 and field2, the goal is to type in a name and when I hit return, have those values become stored in nameArray[] at positions 0 and 1.

I'm not sure whether  the cause is the logic of my action listener or the way I am declaring my array. If it is either of those things...

The array is declared like so, right below my class declaration:

```
public class TwoPlayer{
private String[] nameArray = {};
```

Here is my action listener and field1 initialization:

```
JTextField field1 = new JTextField("Left name");
    field1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String lValue = field1.getText();
    String leftValue = String.valueOf(lValue);
    nameArray[0] = (leftValue);
    }
  });
```

field2:

```
JTextField field2 = new JTextField("Right name");   
    field2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String rValue = field2.getText();
    String rightValue = String.valueOf(rValue);
    nameArray[1] = (rightValue);
    }
  });
```

Obligatory Stack:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at tests.TwoPlayer$1.actionPerformed(TwoPlayer.java:37)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:508)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:721)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:836)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6312)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4762)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the way you are initializing the array. You currently have `private String[] nameArray = {};` which creates a new `String[]` with length 0 and explains the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

What you want instead is `private String[] nameArray = new String[2];` which initializes a `String[]` that will hold two strings.

Comment: Fixed, but I've now got errors on the "String" part of "String[2]" suggesting I create a constant String or a field String

Comment: That one was my fault sorry. You need the `new` keyword in front of it like in the updated answer. `private String[] nameArray = new String[2];`